# isChild(node1, node2) javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Efficient way to implement the follwing function in javascript

```
boolean isChild(node1, node2)

where,
node1 = Considered parent node
node2 = Considered child node

function returns true if node2 is a child of node1 else false
```

Comment: This question shows **no** research effort. Kudos to amnotiam for bothering to do the work for you, *I certainly wouldn't have*. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @Matt: I think you're right. I normally don't answer *"questions"* like this, but it caught my curiosity somehow. @@Tamil: In the future please give some indication of what you've tried, and where you've run into trouble.

Comment: @Matt sorry for not mentioning the purpose. Will keep that in mind in my next question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function isChild(node1, node2) {
    return node2 && node2.parentNode === node1;
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/pPaKy/

Comment: Thanks @AdamRackis. It was sort of a goal, but now that I've reached it, I think I'll probably stop *(or nearly stop)* answering questions. You're going to have to pick up the slack for me. ;-)

Comment: Ha - I know the feeling.  For me the addiction wasn't really broken until I hit 20K, but hopefully you have better self control than I :) - and I'm not sure if I can fill your dom-expert shoes ...

Comment: @AdamRackis: Eh, you'll do fine. DOM is pretty simple. Just keep your jQuery addiction in check. ;)

Comment: [jQuery is great and does all things](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif) ;)

Comment: @AdamRackis: I love that one. :)